# Given Brownian motion $B_t,B_s$ and $t>s$, how to calculate $P(B_t>0,B_s<0)$?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

As stated, this is an interview question.

Given Brownian motion $B_t,B_s$ and $t>s$, how to calculate $P(B_t>0,B_s<0)$?

Comment: Could you please relate your question to quantitative finance, it looks like it is off topic

Comment: @lehalle, come on, this is a quant interview question and a Brownian motion.

Comment: I am not sure all quant interview questions can be asked here. I ask usually questions about the differences between PCA and ICA, and I would close a question here like that, except if it is related to quant finance (say about yield curve modeling)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $X_t=B_t-B_s$ and $Y_t=-B_t$.  $X_t\sim N(0,t-s)$ and $X_t$ , $Y_s$ are independent.
$$I=P(B_t>0, B_s<0)=P(B_t-B_s>-B_s\,,\, -B_s>0)=P(X_t>Y_s\,, Y_s>0)$$ 
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{s(t-s)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2s}-\frac{x^2}{2(t-s)}\right)dxdy$$ 
Set $$y={\sqrt{s}}\,\,r\sin \theta$$
$$\quad x={\sqrt{t-s}}\,\,r\cos \theta$$
we have
$$dx\,dy=\sqrt{s(t-s)}\,r \,dr d\theta$$
 $y>0$ and $x>y$
in other words
$${\sqrt{s}}\,\,r\sin \theta<{\sqrt{t-s}}\,\,r\cos \theta$$
i.e
$$\tan \theta <\sqrt{\frac{t-s}{s}}$$
or 
$$\theta<{\tan^{-1}\left({\sqrt{\frac{t-s}{s}}}\right)}=\cos^{-1}{\left({\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}\right)}$$
therefore
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{{\cos^{-1}{\left({\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}\right)}}}\int_0^{\infty}r\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right)drd\theta$$ 
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{{\cos^{-1}{\left({\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}\right)}}}-\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right)\Big{|}_{0}^{\infty}d\theta$$ 
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{{\cos^{-1}{\left({\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}\right)}}}d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}\right)$$

Comment: Please. Brownian motion has beautiful properties.

Comment: can you specify more details about why dydx = $\sqrt{t(t-s)}rdrd\theta$

Comment: $$\begin{align}
  & dydx=Jdrd\theta  \\ 
 & dydx=\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta }  \\
   \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta }  \\
\end{matrix} \right|drd\theta  \\ 
 & dydx=\left| \begin{matrix}
   \sqrt{t}\cos \theta  & -\sqrt{t}r\sin \theta   \\
   \sqrt{t-s}\sin \theta  & \sqrt{t-s}r\cos \theta   \\
\end{matrix} \right|drd\theta  \\ 
 & dydx=\left( \sqrt{t(t-s)}\,r{{\cos }^{2}}\theta +\sqrt{t(t-s)}\,r{{\sin }^{2}}\theta  \right)drd\theta =\sqrt{t(t-s)}\,rdrd\theta  \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand why the lower limit is pi/4.  Surely it corresponds to tan theta = a function of s and t

Comment: @ PythonNewHand Where?

Comment: $J\to |J|......$

Comment: Is there a problem? dydx=J(u,v)dudvdydx=J(u,v)dudv, y shoube be on the first line of Jacobi det  \begin{align}   & dydx=Jdrd\theta  \\   & dydx=\left| \begin{matrix}    \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta }  \\    \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta }  \\ \end{matrix} \right|drd\theta  \\    \end{align}

Comment: @PythonNewHand $dydx=|J| drd\theta$

Comment: absolute value of $J$

Comment: I see, isn't it better to use \begin{align}   & dydx=|J|drd\theta  \end{align}

Comment: I am under the impression that with a very small s and a very big t one would get an intuitive probability of 1/4 (the BM could go up or down just after zero: 1/2 probability and will be above or below zero independently at very big t: 1/2 probability) while your formula give 1/8. Do you have an explanation for that intuition being true or false ?

Comment: Note $P  \left( \,B(s)>0\,,\, B(t)>0 \right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi }{{\cos }^{- 1}}\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}$

Comment: $$P(B_t>0 , B_s<0)\ne P \left( \,B(s)>0\,,\, B(t)>0 \right)$$

Comment: It appears to give me some more confidence in my intuition as s being small to t in your formula give $P(B(s)>0, B(t)>0) = 1/4 + o(s/t)$. We hence have $P(B(s)<0, B(t)<0) = 1/4 + o(s/t)$ because $-B_t$ is also a standard BM. Given the normalisation: $P(B(s)>0, B(t)>0)+P(B(s)<0, B(t)>0)+P(B(s)>0, B(t)<0)+P(B(s)<0, B(t)<0)=1$,
we then have $P(B(s)<0, B(t)>0)+P(B(s)>0, B(t)<0) = 1/2 + o(s/t)$ and then with the same consideration on $-B_t$ being a standard BM we have $P(B(s)<0, B(t)>0) = P(B(s)>0, B(t)<0)$ thus giving $P(B(s)<0, B(t)>0) = 1/4 + o(s/t)$.

Comment: I see how $B_t-B_s$ is independent to $B_s$ but i am not sure about  $B_t-B_s$ being independent to $B_t$.

Comment: Thanks. it was edited. Also $$\operatorname{Cov}(B_t-B_s,-B_s)=\operatorname{Cov}(B_t,-B_s)+\operatorname{Cov}(B_s,-B_s)=-\min\{t,s\}+\operatorname{Var}(-B_s)=-s+s=0$$ therefore $\rho=0$

Comment: With previous consideration, should not  we have $P(B_s<0,B_t>0)=1/(2*π) cos^−1(√s/t)$ ?

Comment: Indeed we can change $\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t-s}{s}}\right)$ to $\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}\right)$

Comment: $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$